# how can i count different row values and create new column?

Tags: php, mysql, count, row

i had a table in MySQL like this ,is there any solution:- 
[first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oE0w.jpg)
[image]

but now i need to convert that table into like this :-
[second table would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/godbv.jpg)

[image]

Comment: In the column SIF_SUB how the values are separated? Are they separated with the spaces ?

Comment: yes,they separated with spaces.

Comment: Please embed your images directly in your question. Otherwise your tables are difficult to compare.

Comment: Okay can you show your code samples or whatever you have been tried yet?

Comment: how can i do that , mapek ? i just uploaded those files

Answer (score 0):

```
select col_code,case when instr(sif_sub,'220301')>0 then 1 else 0 end as '220301'
from table;
```

Comment: thats nice jerry- but i need all sub_code sum of all college

Comment: select distinct col_code,case when instr(sif_sub,'220301')>0 then 1 else 0 end as '220301' from table;

Comment: can anyone ans this ques ?? plz

Comment: table corresponding relationship is?

Comment: those subjects , of all students of same college

Comment: SIF_SUB is subject,STD_NAME is student_name?

Comment: yes jerry- i want all subjects number under different college code which taken by students-ex. if 3 students take 3 subjects than count of that subject of that college is 3

Comment: this is not so good.if the subject scope is clear,i feel use ' case when ' clause for only way,or you can create a function for deal.